# Create a list of combinations of all values from one column with all values from another in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

Is there any formulaic way of recursively working through one column and combining it with values from another? For illustration, given...

Column A:

```
A
B
C
```

and

Column B:

```
1 
2 
3
```

can I generate...

Column C:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
B3
C1
C2
C3
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)), COUNTA(B1:B)), CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(B1:B&CHAR(9), COUNTA(A1:A))), CHAR(9)))))
```

[image: 0]